# Send Mail with python using gmail smtp

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am using following code

```
import smtplib
import mimetypes
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

emailfrom = "sender@example.com"
emailto = "destination@example.com"
fileToSend = "hi.csv"
username = "user"
password = "password"

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = emailfrom
msg["To"] = emailto
msg["Subject"] = "help I cannot send an attachment to save my life"
msg.preamble = "help I cannot send an attachment to save my life"

ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fileToSend)
if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
    ctype = "application/octet-stream"

maintype, subtype = ctype.split("/", 1)

if maintype == "text":
    fp = open(fileToSend)
    # Note: we should handle calculating the charset
    attachment = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
    fp.close()
elif maintype == "image":
    fp = open(fileToSend, "rb")
    attachment = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
    fp.close()
elif maintype == "audio":
    fp = open(fileToSend, "rb")
    attachment = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
    fp.close()
else:
    fp = open(fileToSend, "rb")
    attachment = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
    attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=fileToSend)
msg.attach(attachment)

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(emailfrom, emailto, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

I am getting error
"Username and password not accepted. learn more at\n5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257"
as per written over there, i have changed Allow less secure apps: ON

but getting same error!
any help??

Comment: Is the username you're using the full address. eg: name@gmail.com

Comment: yes! username password are correctly inserted while executing!

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) (I'm the developer) is to make it really easy to send emails, especially with HTML or attachment needs.

Try the following code:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(username, password)
yag.send(emailto, subject = "I now can send an attachment", contents = fileToSend)
```

Notice the magic here: `contents` equal to a file path will automatically attach, using correct mimetype.

If you want to send text with it you can do like so:

```
contents = ['Please see the attachment below:', fileToSend, 'cool huh?']
```

If you want to talk about the attachment instead of sending it, just make sure no argument in the list is ONLY the filepath.

```
contents = 'This filename will not be attached ' + fileToSend
```

You can get yagmail by using pip to install it:

```
pip install yagmail # Python 2
pip3 install yagmail # Python 3
```

Comment: Just off the question, does it detect the mimetype automatically?

Comment: @0xc0de Yes, it does!

Comment: @JamesMethew `pip3 install yagmail`, or perhaps `pip3.2 install yagmail` can be tried?

Comment: @JamesMethew Perhaps try running `which python3` and `which pip3`.

Comment: pip3 and python3 both